# Comparing Date values in TextBox/Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make sure that users don't enter any date that can be earlier than 'fromdate' which I achieved. Problem is users also should be able to write one specifix text ("UFN") to second textbox(validitydate1).

For example, when a user enter a date which is later than first textbox(validitydate), they can be able move on to next pages but if they enter a date which is earlier than what they entered into first textbox, they shouldn't be able to move on to next pages.In addition to that, they should be able to write ("UFN") into second textbox as well.

When I enter a date to fromdate and write "UFN" into todate I am getting same msgbox error.

Is there a way to move on to next page, if I write "UFN" into 'todate' and not getting this msgbox error?

```
Private Sub GoToNext_Click()


Dim fromdate As Date
Dim todate As Date


On Error Resume Next
fromdate = Me.ValidityDate.value
todate = Me.ValidityDate1.value

If todate < fromdate Then
MsgBox "Check the validity dates please!", vbExclamation
Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`! This line just hides **all** error messages until `End Sub` but the errors still occur. If you use that this way you are not able to see your errors and therefore you cannot debug/fix your code. Remove it and tell which errors you get.

Comment: When I write "UFN" into second textbox and moving to next page, I am getting run-time error '13', type mismatch which highlight                                             todate = Me.ValidityDate1.value line.

Comment: "UFN" is not a date, it's a string. VBA can perform mathmetical operations like `<` on  string. You'll need to add a `IF` to handle when user enters `UFN`.

Comment: Yes I know but I could not figure out what kind of if statement could solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it since you cannot check for date comparison if "UFN" is entered:

```
If Me.ValidityDate1.Value <> "UFN" Then

    Dim fromdate As Date
    Dim todate As Date

    fromdate = Me.ValidityDate.Value
    todate = Me.ValidityDate1.Value

    If todate < fromdate Then
        MsgBox "Check the validity dates please!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub GoToNext_Click()
    Dim fromdate As Date
    Dim todate As Date

    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    fromdate = CDate(Me.ValidityDate.Value)
    todate = CDate(Me.ValidityDate1.Value)

    If DateDiff("d", todate, fromdate) < 0 Then
        GoTo errorhandler
    End If
    Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    MsgBox "Check the validity dates please!", vbExclamation
End Sub
```